# MS access combo box get selected item value

Tags: ms-access, combobox

Hello -

I'm using MS Access and I'm using a form to run a query. The form has two text boxes, a combo box and a button.

All three provide criteria for the query and the button runs the query when it is clicked. Currently the text boxes are working and they provide the criteria for the query.
The combo box is bound to data from another table and is currently not providing the criteria to the query.

What I would like to do is that when I select an item on the combo box and I run the query using the button, the selected item is the one used as the criteria in the query.

If this requires vba code I would really appreciate if you showed me how its done.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning,

Yes that would require some VBA code to perform. You haven't stated the actual data that would entered into the textboxes, textbox names or whatever but I've created a basic layout of how it would go:

```
Private Sub btnRunSQL_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

'Retrieve data from the form elements
Dim forename As String
forename = Forms!frmTest!txtForename

Dim surname As String
surname = Forms!frmTest!txtSurname

Dim occupation As String
occupation = Forms!frmTest!cmbOccupation

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * " & _
         "FROM Patient " & _
         "WHERE Job = [" & occupation & "] AND Forename = " & forename & " " & _
         "AND Surname = " & surname & "; "

'Print our SQL to see what we are retrieving
Debug.Print strSQL

'Run the constructed SQL statement
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

ErrHandler:

'If an error occurs
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error Number: " + Err.Number + ": Description: " + Err.Description
End If

End Sub
```

Above we can see that I'm explicitly referring to the elements on the form by their names in order top get the information inside of them and am passing each to its own variable. (Note - you'll probably want to do some validation to ensure all these fields are filled before executing the SQL.)

I then construct the SQL based on the values passed and print it out to the immediate window to determine if it was constructed correctly. I then execute the statement using the command:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

I have also ensured that any errors that may arise are handled and presented back to the user via the error handler defined at the button of the function.

One last thing: do you know how to get to the VBA window and how to construct the code specifically for the button?

Do this if you don't:

1. Right click on your button in the form design view mode.
2. Select `Build Event`
3. Select `Code Builder` and hit ok

You'll now be taken to the VBA window (which can also be opened by pressing `Alt + F11`)

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Katana24 I was gone for a while but this truly works. Its a nice simple solution that is easy to implement and really helps